# Paypal Donate button not linking correctly on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, safari, cross-browser

I created a Paypal button for both one-time & recurring donations using some jQuery to switch out the input values so both buttons could be used.

The links function perfectly in both Chrome and Firefox, but when I test it in Safari the submit button just takes it to Paypal's main page, not the checkout. Does anyone have a clue why this might be happening?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="paypal-form">
<input id="paypal-cmd" type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="TBX92MDZ4GV64">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input id="paypal-item-name" type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Monthly Donation to Growing Home">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="75.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribe_SM.gif:NonHosted">

<div id="paypal-donate">
    <h2>Donate</h2>
    <p><input id="paypal-amount" type="text" name="a3" maxlength="10" placeholder="$75" value="$75"></p>
    <div id="donate-once" class="button-off">Today</div>
    <div id="donate-monthly" class="button-on">Monthly</div>
</div>
<div id="paypal-share">
    <h2>Share</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Why do you give?">
    <p><textarea id="paypal-reason" name="os0" placeholder="What's your reason for giving?"></textarea></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Can we quote you?">
    <input type="checkbox" name="os1" id="paypal-quote"><label for="paypal-quote"></label>
    <span class="paypal-quote-label">Can we quote you?<span>
</div>
<div id="paypal-submit">
    <h2>Submit</h2>
    <p>Thank you so much for donating.</p>
    <input type="image" src="donate_sm.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</div>
```

```
var onceButton = jQuery('#donate-once');
var monthlyButton = jQuery('#donate-monthly');

jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
    cb = jQuery(this);
    cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));
});

jQuery(onceButton).click(function(){
    jQuery(onceButton).removeClass('button-off').addClass('button-on');
    jQuery(monthlyButton).removeClass('button-on').addClass('button-off');

    var a = jQuery("input[name=no_note]").val();
    if (a === '1') jQuery("#paypal-cmd").val("_donations"), jQuery("#paypal-item-name").val("One-Time Donation to Growing Home"), jQuery("input[name=src]").val("0"), jQuery("input[name=no_note]").val("0"), jQuery("input[type='hidden'][name=a3]").remove(), jQuery("input[name=a3]").attr('name', 'amount'), jQuery("input[name=p3]").remove(), jQuery("input[name=t3]").remove();
});


jQuery(monthlyButton).click(function(){
    jQuery(monthlyButton).removeClass('button-off').addClass('button-on');
    jQuery(onceButton).removeClass('button-on').addClass('button-off');
    var a = jQuery("input[name=no_note]").val();
    if (a === '0') jQuery("#paypal-cmd").val("_xclick-subscriptions"), jQuery("#paypal-item-name").val("Monthly Donation to Growing Home"), jQuery("input[name=src]").val("1"), jQuery("input[name=no_note]").val("1"), jQuery("input[name=amount]").attr('name', 'a3'), jQuery('#paypal-form').append('<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="75.00"><input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">'); 
});
```

Comment: What version of Safari? I've been hearing a lot about iOS 8.0 breaking things.

Comment: Well, that sounds like fun. Version 7.1